# How to add images to Drupal Commerce Kickstart Slideshow?

Tags: drupal, drupal-commerce

For the life of me I can't figure this out.
I copied the view for the sample slideshow. Now I'm trying to edit the images, but I can't find an option for it anywhere.
How do I create a clean slideshow maybe? I can't find that anywhere either.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done it but the answer should be this:

The slideshow is block created by a view.
That view shows a content type named slideshow.
You can change the content type in the filter criteria of the view...